# Run Shell Script in resources folder in Spring boot Application

Tags: shell, spring-boot

I am trying to execute a shell scripts which is in the resources folder in my spring-boot application. I wish to retrieve the process Id of this execution, but I am not able to figure out how to achieve this.

Could you help me to figure this out?

Thank you

Comment: How are you executing the script? Can you share the code for what you've tried thus far?

Comment: I deleted my code, Now I was able to achieve this using python, because I was not able to achieve the same with python. But if you know how to do this I will appreciate a lot. Thank you in advance.